# Ajax post to web server: size limit error

Tags: ajax

I want to post base64 string but get error: `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializerserializer,Stringinput,Typetype,Int32depthLimit)`
My json has base64 and a little info about image

Ajax:
(photo_data is array keep images info)

```
$.ajax(
   {
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: serviceurl + "buy",
    data:"{'userInfo':'"+JSON.stringify(userInfo)
           +"','photos':'"+JSON.stringify(photo_data)+"','buyS':'asd'}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg)
         {

         },
    error: function()
       {

        }
        });
```

WebServer:

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public String buy(String userInfo,String photos,String buyS)
    {

        return "False";
    }
```

**EDIT:**
When i remove base64 string, it is working. (I am sure `attr('src')` returns base64)

```
var photo=new Object();
//photo.imgSource=$(element).attr('src');
photo.s=s;
photo.c=c;
photo.p=p;
photo_data.push(photo);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you should have done was to increase "maxJsonLength" limitation of ASP.NET. The default is about 100KB, and to send big files like images through WebMethods and WebServices, you should definitely increase that limit.

In the Web.Config file you can change this default limitation to your needs.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="1000000"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

That one is ~1MB. You can set higher values if you need to send bigger files through your webservice.

Check that and please let me know if it works.

EDIT: I recently found out that this is not the only setting you should make. You should also set the "maxRequestLength" attribute of the httpruntime node in web.config file, like:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="10000" executionTimeout="10800" />
</system.web>
```

Here, maxRequestLength is in KBs, so 10000 means ~10MBs (9,77MB exactly). If users have low bandwidths and your requestlength requirement is bigger than 10MB, then you can set executionTimeout attribute to a higher value. That is in seconds, so 10800 means 3 hours.

I think you got the picture here.

Cheers!

Comment: That solved my problem, then c# JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize  problem occurred, i used Json.NET instead. Now it is ok. Thank you

Comment: Glad to help! Take care ;)